# Using magic commands outside of Interactive Shell in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

Is there a way to use "magic commands" from IPython from an outside file? For example if I have a file, "rcode.py" with the code:

```
%load_ext rmagic
%R a=c(1,2,3);b=c(2,3,4);print(summary(lm(a~b)))
```

This gives me a `SyntaxError` for the first line when I run it using `ipython rcode.py` in the command line. However when I type these lines straight into the interactive shell with ipython it runs fine. Is this because you only do magic in the interactive shell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you name your file with a `.ipy` extension, ipython will parse it properly. You can simply make a symlink if you want:

```
$ ln -s rcode.py rcode.ipy
$ ipython rcode.ipy
```