# How can I run a shell command ( written in Vim ) using Ipython?

Tags: shell, vim, ipython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using magic commands outside of Interactive Shell in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219387/using-magic-commands-outside-of-interactive-shell-in-ipython)

I know that Ipython is a powerful python shell. And when I input some shell commands, it works well. However, when I write the same shell commands in vim and run it in Ipython, there is 'SyntaxError'. For example,when I input ‘!ps’ in Ipython, it gives the right answer. However,When I write '!ps' in vim and run it in Ipython, it gives 'SyntaxError'. How can I run python scripts combined with some shell commands in Ipython?

Comment: You mean IPython first, `!vim` in IPython and `!ps` in vim, or what?

Comment: Are you saving a python file containing `!ps` and then trying to run it with `ipython myfile.py` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I know what is wrong. I must save it in myfile.ipy!!

Comment: Your link is helpful. Thank you!